# Serialize Dictionary<string,string> member to XML elements and data

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, dictionary

I have a class 'products' that is serializable to XML. I'm using the standard System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer to serialize and a XmlWriter 'writer' object to write the serialized results to a StreamWriter object. The serializer object now serializes the whole class in one go:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(products));
serializer.Serialize(writer, products);
```

The class has a Dictionary<string,string> member called 'Specifications'. It is dynamically built, so I don't know the keys beforehand. Here's an example of what data the dictionary may contain (key: value):

- color: blue
- length: 110mm
- width: 55mm

I would like to be able to serialize that property into this:

```
...
<specifications>
  <color>blue</color>
  <length>110mm</length>
  <width>55mm</width>
</specifications>
...
```

I know this is poor XML design, but it has to conform to a 3rd party specification.

Is there perhaps a standard attribute that I can use? If not, how would I be able to serialize the dictionary like that?

If you need more code snippets, let me know.

**EDIT**:
Due to some changes in requirement, I let go of the Dictionary<string,string>. Instead, I created a class "Specification":

```
public class Specification
{
    public string Name;
    public string Value;
    public bool IsOther;

    public Specification() : this(null, null, false) { }

    public Specification(string name, string value) : this(name, value, false) { }

    public Specification(string name, string value, bool isOther)
    {
        Name = name;
        Value = value;
        IsOther = isOther;
    }
}
```

To avoid repeating the element "spec" by having a List of "Specification" in the product class, I use a plural class "Specifications" that implements the IXmlSerializable interface:

```
public class Specifications: IXmlSerializable
{
    public List<Specification> Specs = new List<Specification>();

    public XmlSchema GetSchema()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
    {
        //I don't need deserialization, but it would be simple enough now.
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
    {
        //write all "standarad", named specs
        //this writes the <color>blue</color>-like elements
        Specs.Where(s => !s.IsOther).ToList().ForEach(s => writer.WriteElementString(s.Name, s.Value));

        //write other specs
        //this writes <other_specs>{name|value[;]}*</other_specs>
        string otherSpecs = string.Join(";", Specs.Where(s => s.IsOther).Select(s => string.Concat(s.Name, "|", s.Value)));
        if (otherSpecs.Length > 0) writer.WriteElementString("other_specs", otherSpecs);
    }
}
```

The class "Specifications" is applied as:

```
public class Product
{
    public Product()
    {
        Specifications = new Specifications();
    }

    [XmlElement("specs")]
    public Specifications Specifications;

    //this "feature" will not include <specs/> when there are none
    [XmlIgnore]
    public bool SpecificationsSpecified { get { return Specifications.Specs.Any(); } }

    //...
}
```

Thank you for providing examples of IXmlSerializable and XmlWriter. I didn't know that interface and usage of XmlWriter - it proved to be a valuable inspiration for me!

*this was my first SO question. What's the most appropriate way to close it? I didn't provide this as my own answer as it is not a real answer to my initial question (about Dictionary).

Comment: I think [this sample](http://huseyint.com/2007/12/xml-serializable-generic-dictionary-tipi/) could help you: check the `WriteXml` method and change it accordingly to your needs...

Comment: You might have a look here, since Dictionary in itself in unfortunately not serializable: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12856456/c-sharp-serialize-dictionary-parameter-without-parent-node

Comment: Do you know in advance the keys that will appear, or do you need to serialize whatever keys appear?

Comment: Both examples look promising; I'll have a better look tomorrow. Dbc, I don't know which keys beforehand.

Comment: Suggest editing your question to add that you don't know the keys in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your dictionary value are all simple types that can be converted to a string, you can create your own `IXmlSerializable` dictionary wrapper to store and retrieve the keys and values:

```
public class XmlKeyTextValueListWrapper<TValue> : CollectionWrapper<KeyValuePair<string, TValue>>, IXmlSerializable
{
    public XmlKeyTextValueListWrapper() : base(new List<KeyValuePair<string, TValue>>()) { } // For deserialization.

    public XmlKeyTextValueListWrapper(ICollection<KeyValuePair<string, TValue>> baseCollection) : base(baseCollection) { }

    public XmlKeyTextValueListWrapper(Func<ICollection<KeyValuePair<string, TValue>>> getCollection) : base(getCollection) {}

    #region IXmlSerializable Members

    public XmlSchema GetSchema()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
    {
        var converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(TValue));
        XmlKeyValueListHelper.ReadXml(reader, this, converter);
    }

    public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
    {
        var converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(TValue));
        XmlKeyValueListHelper.WriteXml(writer, this, converter);
    }

    #endregion
}

public static class XmlKeyValueListHelper
{
    public static void WriteXml<T>(XmlWriter writer, ICollection<KeyValuePair<string, T>> collection, TypeConverter typeConverter)
    {
        foreach (var pair in collection)
        {
            writer.WriteStartElement(XmlConvert.EncodeName(pair.Key));
            writer.WriteValue(typeConverter.ConvertToInvariantString(pair.Value));
            writer.WriteEndElement();
        }
    }

    public static void ReadXml<T>(XmlReader reader, ICollection<KeyValuePair<string, T>> collection, TypeConverter typeConverter)
    {
        if (reader.IsEmptyElement)
        {
            reader.Read();
            return;
        }

        reader.ReadStartElement(); // Advance to the first sub element of the list element.
        while (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
        {
            var key = XmlConvert.DecodeName(reader.Name);
            string value;
            if (reader.IsEmptyElement)
            {
                value = string.Empty;
                // Move past the end of item element
                reader.Read();
            }
            else
            {
                // Read content and move past the end of item element
                value = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
            }
            collection.Add(new KeyValuePair<string,T>(key, (T)typeConverter.ConvertFromInvariantString(value)));
        }
        // Move past the end of the list element
        reader.ReadEndElement();
    }

    public static void CopyTo<TValue>(this XmlKeyTextValueListWrapper<TValue> collection, ICollection<KeyValuePair<string, TValue>> dictionary)
    {
        if (dictionary == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("dictionary");
        if (collection == null)
            dictionary.Clear();
        else
        {
            if (collection.IsWrapperFor(dictionary)) // For efficiency
                return;
            var pairs = collection.ToList();
            dictionary.Clear();
            foreach (var item in pairs)
                dictionary.Add(item);
        }
    }
}

public class CollectionWrapper<T> : ICollection<T>
{
    readonly Func<ICollection<T>> getCollection;

    public CollectionWrapper(ICollection<T> baseCollection)
    {
        if (baseCollection == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        this.getCollection = () => baseCollection;
    }

    public CollectionWrapper(Func<ICollection<T>> getCollection)
    {
        if (getCollection == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        this.getCollection = getCollection;
    }

    public bool IsWrapperFor(ICollection<T> other)
    {
        if (other == Collection)
            return true;
        var otherWrapper = other as CollectionWrapper<T>;
        return otherWrapper != null && otherWrapper.IsWrapperFor(Collection);
    }

    ICollection<T> Collection { get { return getCollection(); } }

    #region ICollection<T> Members

    public void Add(T item)
    {
        Collection.Add(item);
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        Collection.Clear();
    }

    public bool Contains(T item)
    {
        return Collection.Contains(item);
    }

    public void CopyTo(T[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
        Collection.CopyTo(array, arrayIndex);
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get { return Collection.Count; }
    }

    public bool IsReadOnly
    {
        get { return Collection.IsReadOnly; }
    }

    public bool Remove(T item)
    {
        return Collection.Remove(item);
    }

    #endregion

    #region IEnumerable<T> Members

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return Collection.GetEnumerator();
    }

    #endregion

    #region IEnumerable Members

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

And then use it like so:

```
[XmlRoot("products")]
public class Products
{
    public Products()
    {
        Specifications = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    }

    [XmlIgnore]
    [JsonProperty("specifications")] // For testing purposes, I compare Json.NET serialization before and after XML serialization.  You can remove this.
    public Dictionary<string, string> Specifications { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("specifications")]
    [JsonIgnore] // For testing purposes, I compare Json.NET serialization before and after XML serialization.  You can remove this.
    public XmlKeyTextValueListWrapper<string> XmlSpecifications
    {
        get
        {
            return new XmlKeyTextValueListWrapper<string>(() => this.Specifications);
        }
        set
        {
            value.CopyTo(Specifications = (Specifications ?? new Dictionary<string, string>()));
        }
    }
}
```

The fact that your dictionary values are simple types (directly convertible from and to text) makes it possible to avoid nested creations of `XmlSerializer`, which is more complex.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28769495/how-to-derive-xml-element-name-from-an-attribute-value-of-a-class-using-annotati) for an example.

Comment: This was, among with the links in the comments to my original question, the most valuable answer. See my edit for my final solution.

Answer (score 0):

Make the dictionary NonSerialized

```css
[XmlRoot("specifications")]
    public class Specifications
    {
         [NonSerialized]
         Dictionary<string, string> dict { get; set; }
         [XmlElement("color")]
         string color {get;set;}
         [XmlElement("length")]
         string length { get; set; }
         [XmlElement("width")]
         string width { get; set; }

         public Specifications()
         {
             dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
         }
    }
```

Comment: The thing is, I don't know which keys will be in it. There may be none, three or twenty. It is built dynamically and is dependant per product.