# How do you deserialize XML with dynamic element names?

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

My XML looks like follows:

```
<rates>
    <rate1>1250.00</rate1>
    <rate2>1900.00</rate2>
</rates>
```

This is in my Serializable class:

```
[XmlRoot("main")]
public class Main
{
    [XmlArray("rates"), XmlAnyElement]
    public Rates Rates { get; set; }
}

public class Rates : List<Rate> { }

public class Rate
{
    [XmlAnyElement]
    public string Rate;
}
```

How can I deserialize the XML so that I can access it using:

```
var rate1 = Main.Rates[0].Rate;
var rate2 = Main.Rates[1].Rate;
```

Comment: You don't need dynamic deserialization here. You will have a list of rates within your Rates list. It is therefore perfectly correct that they should be statically named, but dynamically valued.

Comment: @montewhizdoh Apologies, I have fixed the XML, but that is not the issue.

Comment: Sometimes, if I'm just reading small amounts of data, I just use a regex to transform replace the XML string before parsing. Sometimes its the least amount of change.

Comment: You may need to implement `IXmlSerializable` by using `XmlKeyTextValueListWrapper<decimal>` from [Serialize Dictionary<string,string> member to XML elements and data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29795747).

Comment: If you want to use `[XmlAnyElement]` instead you will need to do something along the lines of [How to deserialize xml elements that have different names, but the same set of attributes to a typed array/collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30910834/how-to-deserialize-xml-elements-that-have-different-names-but-the-same-set-of-a/30925157#30925157) - but simpler because you won't need to invoke a nested `XmlSerializer` for your decimal values.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this by having your `Rates` collection [implement `IXmlSerializable`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279534/proper-way-to-implement-ixmlserializable):

```
public class Rates : List<Rate>, IXmlSerializable
{
    public Rates() : base() { }
    public Rates(IEnumerable<Rate> collection) : base(collection) { }

    #region IXmlSerializable Members

    XmlSchema IXmlSerializable.GetSchema()
    {
        return null;
    }

    void IXmlSerializable.ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
    {
        // for the `decodeName` delegate, you could check that the node name matches the pattern "rateN" for some integer N, if you want.
        XmlKeyValueListHelper.ReadXml(reader, this, null, s => new Rate { RateValue = s });
    }

    void IXmlSerializable.WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
    {
        XmlKeyValueListHelper.WriteXml(writer, this, (i, rate) => "rate" + XmlConvert.ToString(i), r => r.RateValue);
    }

    #endregion
}

public class Rate
{
    public string RateValue;
}

public static class XmlKeyValueListHelper
{
    const string XsiNamespace = @"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";
    const string XsiNil = "nil";

    public static void WriteXml<T>(XmlWriter writer, IEnumerable<T> collection, Func<int, T, string> encodeName, Func<T, string> encodeValue)
    {
        int i = 0;
        foreach (var item in collection)
        {
            writer.WriteStartElement(XmlConvert.EncodeLocalName(encodeName(i, item)));
            if (item == null)
            {
                writer.WriteAttributeString(XsiNil, XsiNamespace, XmlConvert.ToString(true));
            }
            else
            {
                writer.WriteValue(encodeValue(item) ?? "");
            }
            writer.WriteEndElement();
            i++;
        }
    }

    public static void ReadXml<T>(XmlReader reader, ICollection<T> collection, Func<int, string, bool> decodeName, Func<string, T> decodeValue)
    {
        if (reader.IsEmptyElement)
        {
            reader.Read();
            return;
        }

        int i = 0;
        reader.ReadStartElement(); // Advance to the first sub element of the list element.
        while (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
        {
            var key = XmlConvert.DecodeName(reader.Name);
            if (decodeName == null || decodeName(i, key))
            {
                var nilValue = reader[XsiNil, XsiNamespace];
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(nilValue) && XmlConvert.ToBoolean(nilValue))
                {
                    collection.Add(default(T));
                    reader.Skip();
                }
                else
                {
                    string value;
                    if (reader.IsEmptyElement)
                    {
                        value = string.Empty;
                        // Move past the end of item element
                        reader.Read();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Read content and move past the end of item element
                        value = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
                    }
                    collection.Add(decodeValue(value));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                reader.Skip();
            }
            i++;
        }
        // Move past the end of the list element
        reader.ReadEndElement();
    }
}
```

Example [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/PCC6YI).

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic element names can be simple to process using the `XmlSerializer.UnknownElement` event handler.

For example, we have following xml:

```
<main>
  <rates>
    <rate1>1250.00</rate1>
    <rate2>1900.00</rate2>
  </rates>
</main>
```

and classes:

```
[XmlRoot("main")]
public class Main
{
    public List<Rate> Rates { get; set; }
}

public class Rate
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Do deserialize:

```
var xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Main));
// add event handler
xs.UnknownElement += Xs_UnknownElement;

Main main;
using (var fs = new FileStream("test.xml", FileMode.Open))
    main = (Main)xs.Deserialize(fs);
```

The event handler code:

```
private void Xs_UnknownElement(object sender, XmlElementEventArgs e)
{
    Main main = (Main)e.ObjectBeingDeserialized;

    foreach (XmlNode node in e.Element.ChildNodes)
        main.Rates.Add(new Rate { Value = node.InnerText });
}
```