# Serializing a c# list and want a different name for each item

Tags: c#, serialization

I have the following:

```
[XmlArrayItem("ScheduleClassic")]
public ScheduleCollection Classes { get; set; }
```

Which produces the following:

```
<Classes>
  <ScheduleClassic>
      list of elements...
  </ScheduleClassic>
  <ScheduleClassic>
      list of elements...
  </ScheduleClassic>
</Classes
```

What I want to produce is the following with a number appended to each one for a count.

```
<Classes>
  <ScheduleClassic1>
      list of elements...
  </ScheduleClassic>
  <ScheduleClassic2>
      list of elements...
  </ScheduleClassic2>
</Classes>
```

Comment: So you want something to serialize the index of each item in the list, along with the item?

Comment: Why? If all ScheduleClassics are of the same element type, why are you renaming the elements to be something different?

Comment: The data is being sent to a third party and that is the structure that they are asking for.

Comment: You could just add an attribute with an index if you really needed the numerical representation of the index.

Comment: I suppose you should implement `IXmlSerializable` for your `scheduleClassic`-class to write the number of the element also. 

Another way would be to add an attribute to the xml-tag, which looks like this: `<scheduleClassic id="1">...`.

Comment: I don't really recommend doing this since it makes it difficult to create an [XSD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Schema_(W3C)) for your type.  That being said, does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37262084/3744182) do what you want?  Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/PCC6YI).