# How to Serialize xml and get just deepest nodes

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, deserialization, linq-to-xml

I have the following xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
    <file_1>
        <file_name Value="" />
        <date Value="" />
        <information>
            <page1>
                <percentage Value="90%" />                
                <profit Value="50%" />                
                <total Value="$1500" />                
            </page1>
        </information>
    </file_1>
</root>
```

and I want to serialize that xml but I want that all subnodes in page1 node could be handle like properties, for example:

```
var xmlInfo = new List<xmlClass>();
var FieldName = xmlInfo[0].FieldName; // the value of FieldName should be percentage
var data = xmlInfo[0].Value; // the value of data should be 90%
```

In other words, I'm only interested in the deepest nodes to serialize them into an object.

I have a serialization method, but I don't know how to build the class.

```
public static T Deserialize<T>(XDocument doc)
        {
            XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

            using (var reader = doc.Root.CreateReader())
            {
                return (T)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(reader);
            }
        }
```

Comment: What makes the XML "special"? What is `xmlClass`?

Comment: I just change the title

Comment: [Does this answer your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37255149/how-do-you-deserialize-xml-with-dynamic-element-names)?

Comment: Can you be a little more specific on "deepest nodes"?  You don't want it to get the values from "file_name" and "date"?

Answer (score 0):

Use xml linq with a dictionary :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            Dictionary<string, string> dict = doc.Descendants("page1")
                .First()
                .Elements()
                .GroupBy(x => x.Name.LocalName, y => (string)y.Attribute("Value"))
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The XPath expression `//*[not(child::node())]` returns all elements without child nodes (either child elements or child text nodes), if that matches your definition of "deepest".